# spacy nlp.pipe then check like num doesn't work

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I read a documentation saying nlp.pipe() has a better performance to deal with a large amount of data.

And the way to iterate is by calling the list of it.

But When I run this code, checking if the token is like a num doesn't work.
and I checked the type of the object and it returns doc object not token object.

What should I do to check if the individual words are like_num and remove those?

```
dummylist=[];

for ingrendient in ingredients:
    dummylist.append(nlp.pipe(ingrendient))

dummylist[0]
    
a=list(dummylist[0])

# [12 egg whites,
#  12 egg yolks,
#  1 1/2 cups sugar,
#  3/4 cup rye whiskey,
#  12 egg whites,
#  3/4 cup brandy,
#  1/2 cup rum,
#  1 to 2 cups heavy cream, lightly whipped,
#  Garnish: ground nutmeg]

type(a[0])
# spacy.tokens.doc.Doc

[token.like_num for token in a]
# AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'like_num'
```

I assume I have to turn the doc object into token but I got stuck from the point.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop through a list of docs. To get tokens, you need to loop through each doc. Something like:

`[token.like_num for token in doc for doc in a]`